# Asking a professor to be on my committee (not advisor) before admission

Tags: graduate-admissions, thesis-committee

I am applying to a PhD program at my alma mater this fall, and I am trying to make my application as strong as possible. A friend who went through the program suggested that having people lined up to be on my dissertation committee before I applied would help my application.

I have a professor who has agreed to be my advisor if I am admitted, and another professor who has agreed to be on my committee if I am admitted.

I have a meeting with a third professor next week that I have never met before, but was introduced to by another professor. Aspects of his work are very similar to my interests, and I would love if he would be the third person on my committee, but I don't know how to go about asking if he would be willing when we meet.

> Do you have any advice on how to approach this meeting and this professor? How much will having all three professors necessary for my thesis committee on board when I apply help my application?

Comment: Have you checked the rules for the composition of your committee? Have you discussed this with your proposed advisor?

Comment: I have checked the rules for the composition of the committee and he meets all of the requirements that I need for the final person on my committee (in addition to doing really interesting research!). Going to my proposed advisor is a really good idea, unfortunately she is unable to answer e-mail until after the meeting with this third professor (she is traveling).

Comment: I would wait until you can consult your advisor before discussing committee membership. She may know someone else who would be an even better choice. Meeting the professor and discussing your research is useful anyway.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why _you_ think that lining up your doctoral committee prior to being accepted is a good idea? To me, it seems a lot like putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: Is it usual at this institution to line up a committee so early?  In my experience (US), you don't usually form a committee until your second or third year in the program.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! A friend who went through the program suggested that having people lined up before I applied would help my application. I see Patricia's point about talking to him and discussing our research interests on this first meeting, and then talking to my potential advisor on how to move forward from there. As for Nate's question on if it is usual to line up a committee this early, no it is not, but I have connections at this institution, and it is my top choice institution, so I figured I would use every advantage I have.

Comment: I have edited your question to include relevant information from your comments. Please check to make sure that I have maintained the spirit of your question. If you don't like the edit, you can always rollback to a previous version.

Comment: I am curious why you think lining up a committee at this stage would be any sort of advantage.

Comment: Lining up the committee this early has definite disadvantages. Your area of research may shift as you learn more about it. The top professor in your field may join the department next year - you would have loved to have her on your committee, it if were not already filled.

Comment: You have all given me a lot to think about. I won't ask this professor to serve on my committee, but I will talk to him about my research and his research when we meet. I will also ask my future advisor for advice on how to move forward. Patricia, if you write an answer to this question, I will mark it as answered. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Can you please turn your comments into an answer?

Comment: To what country are you referring to? There is a lot variation between countries. It seems people often assume that all questions are related to US academia, but it needs to be specified!

Answer (score 1):

Lining up the committee this early has definite disadvantages. Your area of research may shift as you learn more about it. The top professor in your field may join the department next year - you would have loved to have her on your committee, it if were not already filled.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you are wasting your time and their time. There is a lot of variation across countries regarding what, when, and how a phd committee is formed and this is not something you want to do before being admitted. Focus on your potential advisor, you only need one person to promote your application during the admission process, so there is no use to contact potential committee member when you might not even get an interview or an offer.

I advice instead two things:
1. In your application you can usually include 1-2 other faculty you might be interested in.
2. If you get to the interview stage and you are invited on campus, schedule meetings with these potential committee members.

Lastly, because there are many dynamics inside the department and within research groups, you will not be able to make a realistic short-list of potential committee member until you are at least a few months into the program. If I were a professor and you are an applicant asking me to be in your committee, I would think you are jumping ahead of yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would not ask for either type of commitment -- being an advisor or being in the committee -- at this early stage.

You don't know what kind of horse trading goes on in the admissions committee. Sometimes I've managed to get more than one student because another faculty member out of left field said they wanted to work primarily with that student before I spoke up.

I am also very hesitant of overcommitting myself to too many students.

Instead, if I were you, I would ask if they would be "willing to work with you" if you were accepted. Non-committal and thus easy to answer.